# multiple logic operators in c

Tags: c, comparison, logical-operators

Alright, so how "nice" does C play with using multiple logic operators in one `if` statement? For example, if I want to compare two points, to see if one is adjacent to the other, would it work to use `if(X1 == X2 && Y1-- == Y2 || Y1++ == Y2 || Y1 == Y2 && X1-- == X2 || X1++ == X2)` or do I need to break it up into 4 `else if` statements?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but modifying the X and Y values with the `++` and `--` operators is probably not  a good idea. Instead of writing e.g. `Y1++ == Y2` I'd rather write  `Y1 + 1 == Y2`

Answer (score 4):

You can absolutely use the way you are doing as long as you use `()` properly to determine which conditions are the part of the outer parathenses and which one is the part of the inner one. For instance, assuming your condition is true only if `X1 == X2` and `Y1-- == Y2 || Y1++ == Y2 || Y1 == Y2` and `X1-- == X2 || X1++ == X2`. then use parathenses properly, like this:

```
if( (X1 == X2) && (Y1-- == Y2 || Y1++ == Y2 || Y1 == Y2) && (X1-- == X2 || X1++ == X2) )
```

This condition without parentheses makes it very complicated to understand, and you are likely to make an error.

Comment: So, then if parens work here to indicate order, why have I gotten errors in the past when I used parens to indicate OOS for arithmetic when doing an assignment?